# Couch Base Configuration Using REST APIs

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I am trying to do auto configuration of CouchBase:

- Cluster
- Admin User
- Bucket
- Bucket User
- Services for couch base (data,kv,n1ql,index,fts,search)

Using the rest api everything goes well but i can see while doing the manual configuration i can see the service option during the cluster creation:

[image]

But, while craeating the cluster sevice using the RESI api when i am trying to pass `data` as service its saying:

```
[
    "Unknown services: [\"data\"]"
]
```

REST API I am using to create service:

```
http://localhost:8091/node/controller/setupServices
```

Please suggest me am i doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Can you post your whole request please?

Answer (score 2):

In the REST API the data service is referred to as "kv" (for key-value).

Comment: is there any way that we can assign the memory for this KV because in the above screen we can see that we can assign memory for data service.

Comment: I think the argument for data service ram size is "memoryQuota", which should be an integer number of MB. Also, the 'couchbase-cli' command line tool has options for all of these, and is better documented.